# How to install kubernetes binaries (including kubelet, kubctl, kubeadm) on windows machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am new to kubernetes. Basically,I am trying to add windows node to cluster(contains linux node). My host machine is linux. For now, i am trying to add only 1 windows node but in future it should work for multiple windows nodes). **while joining windows node to the kubernetes cluster using kubeadm** it's throwing error message,

As it is trying to execute "kubeadm join.." on windows node, i am trying to install kubeadm on windows machine. but no luck.

it's throwing error as

```
"fatal: [windows]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": true,
  "cmd": "kubeadm join <IP>:<port> --token <jdhsjhsjdhsd> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<somekey> --node-name <kubernetes_node_hostname>",
  "delta": "0:00:00.732545",
  "end": "2018-12-27 07:39:26.496097",
  "msg": "non-zero return code",
  "rc": 1,
  "start": "2018-12-27 07:39:25.763552",
  "stderr": "kubeadm : The term 'kubeadm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. \r\nCheck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ ... :InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false;"
```

Comment: On which version of kubernetes you're on?

Answer (score 4):

You can download all the various binaries from links in the Changelog for each release. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.13.md#downloads-for-v1131 is the latest 1.13 as this writing.

https://dl.k8s.io/v1.13.1/kubernetes-node-windows-amd64.tar.gz are the node binaries in particular which includes Kubeadm as well as other things needed to run a node.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have already downloaded the binaries but due to organization  firewalls, i am not able to use standard commands like yum, etc. could you please help me out with the command to install it.

Comment: Windows doesn't have any standard commands like that anyway, what I linked is literally just a tarball of the executables.